# Firebase var user returns "null" after popup facebook login

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm tying to create a Facebook login that utilizes my firebase database and prints the logged in users info for that user to review. Basically a profile page that prints information depending on who's logged in.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "mykey",
    authDomain: "authdomain",
    databaseURL: ".firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-123.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  // Get a reference to the database service
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var database = firebase.database();
</script>
<script>
function logIn() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    alert(user);
    // ...
    if (user != null) {
        user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
        alert("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
        alert("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
        alert("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
        alert("  Email: "+profile.email);
        alert("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
        });
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
}

</script>
<button onclick="logIn()">Log In</button><br>
<button onclick="profile()">button</button>
```

I've tried using code snippets from the firebase documentation but nothing seems to be working. Each time, I click the login button the popup appears and no errors log to the console but the var user is still null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating the `user` variable after the user has signed in:

```
function logIn() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    user = result;
    // The signed-in user info.
    alert(user);
    // ...
    if (user != null) {
        user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
        alert("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
        alert("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
        alert("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
        alert("  Email: "+profile.email);
        alert("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
        });
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
}
```

By the way: the [Firebase documentation recommends that you use `onAuthStateChanged` to monitor when the user signs in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

The reason this is preferred is that it also works correctly when the user reloads the page.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm sure I tried that at one point but it never worked but just tried it and it printed everything perfectly!